# fields are not displaying in IE7 after page refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

I have wrote to the code of displaying(hide/show) the fields when checkbox is checked. The javascript is below

```
if(document.getElementById("checkBox") != null){
            if(!document.getElementById("checkBox").checked){
                document.getElementById("displayField1").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("displayField2").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("displayField3").style.display = "none";
            }else{
                document.getElementById("displayField1").style.display = "";
                document.getElementById("displayField2").style.display = "";
                document.getElementById("displayField3").style.display = "";
            }
        }
```

In JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if ($('#checkBox').is(':checked')) {
                    $("#displayField1").show();
                    $("#displayField2").show();
                    $("#displayField3").show();
                } else {
                    $("#displayField1").hide();
                    $("#displayField2").hide();
                    $("#displayField3").hide();
                } 
        });
```

It is working fine in IE8 but not in IE7, after the page is refreshed. I have tried jquery as well but still facing this issue.

Comment: May I suggest "don't support IE7"?

Comment: Have you tried on other browsers like firefox or chrome

Comment: @polin "it is working fine in IE8"

Comment: @polin. It is working fine in IE8, firfox. But not in IE7

Answer (score 0):

You could use a compatibility library to add IE7 support:

http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/